# Element on same line not causing space to appear in between buttons CSS

Tags: html, css, whitespace

Can anyone explain this odd behavior, why extra spacing is adding in between buttons.

**Case -**

Following is the HTML code which is adding extra space in between buttons if written like this -

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <button class="btn one">First long button with a long text length</button>
        <button class="btn two">Second long button with a long text length</button>
    </div>
```

**Output -**

[image: Space Between Buttons]

BUT if I am writing like this then no space is coming -

**Code -**

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <button class="btn one">First long button with a long text length</button><button class="btn two">Second long button with a long text length</button>
    </div>
```

**Output -**

[image: No Space Button]

**CSS Code -**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 28px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline;
}

.btn:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 4%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #FFF;
  right: 0px;
  top: -5px;
}

.two {
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With inline-elements, line-breaks (and multiple spaces) are converted to 1 space.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you can do in order to eliminate white-space between elements; however it depends on the kind of elements used and the browser's html rendering engine.

Here are some things that work for the "white-space" issues, but bare in mind that ultimately you want your code to look neat.

**Good solution** .: *no white-space & clever CSS*
Coding your HTML with no white-space will definitely sort this out for most major browsers, but it makes your code illegible; however you can run your code through an HTML pre-processor (like PHP) and `minify` your code before serving it to the browser. This may seem "daft" for speed concerns, but if you can get clever with "configuration" of your projects in your pre-processor to "bake" (minify) your source-code as a separate file while in "development" mode; and only "serve" the minified code when in "live" mode.

If you prefer the "pre-processor" option then have a look at: [how to minify html code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815755/how-to-minify-html-code)

In your CSS, take note of how different elements render in the browser.
With "block-type" & "view-port" elements, wrap them inside other elements you can control; because styling these to be displayed `inline` may cause issues, hence why the CSS value for these: `display:inline-block`, but it's not a 100% guarantee to look as intended.

**HTML only** .: *comments & weird closing-angle placement .: ugly but works*

```
<button>one</button><!--
--><button>two</button>

<button>one</button
><button>one</button>
```

**CSS only** .: *font-size zero on parent, consistent position & margin*
If you're using the `font-size:0px` then you have to be smart with your CSS selectors. Forcing standard margins/padding for all your elements is a good idea for consistency:

```
body{font-size:0px;}
p,b,i,a,span{font-size:16px;}
div,svg{position:relative; box-sizing:border-box; margin:0px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The \n is a legal character in html, it just don't return line.
You can resolve it by adding font-size:0 to the container of the buttons for example, as the buttons have font-size:14px.

```
div.wrapper { font-size:0 ; }
```

Just be carefull with the other elements in your wrapper wich will heritate from your font-size:0.
OR : you can write in on the same line... :)